# can't save style.css in chrome developer tools

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, google-chrome-devtools, file-access

I've made all these little CSS modifications to [my blog](http://longgame.org/) with Google Chrome's built in Developers tools to improve a +WordPress blog.

I'm using the context-sensitive *Save As* command on the **revised style.css** document. However, none of my changes are reflected in the replaced styles.css document on the server.

A few added details:

1. I am using FileZilla to connect and manually delete the old file, then upload the revision (I've found that replacing doesn't always work, for whatever reason.
2. I'm doing this within the main theme folder for the blog. I am unaware of any other possible location where this could reside.

Thoughts? My original G+ query (with accompanying screenshot) can be found [here](https://plus.google.com/111803955882817854729/posts/SfrP7RADjFY).

Many thanks, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the styles you should append them at the end of the style sheet. I usually create a comment the end something like `/* New Styles Here */` Better yet you should create a child theme and all the styles to the child themes style.css

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I probably _should_ do that, but I'm just *awful*. :) I'm actually doing the same thing I _was_ doing, with the exception that I'm manually entering the changes into my **styles.css** that I have open within Dreamweaver.